# copy template data sets into same table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm searching for a sql query that copy entries based on a template into the same table.

the simplified table looks as follows:

```
  product  | model  | version  |  attribute    | attributeValue 
 ----------|--------|----------|---------------|---------------- 
  A        |     1  |       0  | price         | 1000           
  A        |     1  |       0  | token         | 1              
  A        |     1  |       0  | spc_weight    | 130            
  A        |     1  |       0  | spc_volume    | 150            
  A        |     1  |       0  | spc_diameter  | 12             
  A        |     1  |       0  | colour        | blue           
  A        |     1  |       1  | price         | 1100           
  A        |     1  |       1  | token         | 1              
  A        |     1  |       1  | spc_weight    | 130            
  A        |     1  |       1  | spc_volume    | 150            
  A        |     1  |       1  | spc_diameter  | 12             
  A        |     1  |       1  | colour        | blue           
  B        |     1  |       0  | price         | 800            
  B        |     1  |       0  | token         | 1              
  B        |     1  |       0  | spc_weight    | 135            
  B        |     1  |       0  | spc_volume    | 150            
  B        |     1  |       0  | spc_diameter  | 12             
  B        |     1  |       0  | colour        | red            
  B        |     2  |       0  | price         | 800            
  B        |     2  |       0  | token         | 1              
  B        |     2  |       0  | spc_weight    | 140            
  B        |     2  |       0  | spc_volume    | 150            
  B        |     2  |       0  | spc_diameter  | 12             
  B        |     2  |       0  | colour        | red            
  C        |     1  |       0  | price         | 800            
  C        |     1  |       0  | token         | 2              
  C        |     1  |       0  | spc_weight    | 135            
  C        |     1  |       0  | spc_volume    | 155            
  C        |     1  |       0  | spc_diameter  | 12             
  C        |     1  |       0  | colour        | green
```

i have also created here the table --> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c6b01/3

- **what's the template?** the template product (product+model+version) is user defined.
- **what data should be copied?** all spc_% attributeValue from template product
- **where should the data be copied?** the attributeValue from the template needs to copied into the corresponding attribute from all product that have the same token attribute and are the latest version.

what I have at the moment is

**get the template data**

```
select attributeValue from product
where product='B'  and model =1 and version =0 and attribute like 'spc_%'
```

**what products are affected**

```
select product, model, max (version) as version from product
where  attribute='token' and attributeValue='1' 
group by product, model
```

so the solution in that case would be that all the attribute spc_% for product A model 1 version 1  and product B model 2 version 0 are populated with the attributeValue from the template product b model 1 version 0

thats how the table should look after the update. the values with * are the one that should have been updated based on the template.

```
  product  | model  | version  |  attribute    | attributeValue 
 ----------|--------|----------|---------------|---------------- 
  A        |     1  |       0  | price         | 1000           
  A        |     1  |       0  | token         | 1              
  A        |     1  |       0  | spc_weight    | 130            
  A        |     1  |       0  | spc_volume    | 150            
  A        |     1  |       0  | spc_diameter  | 12             
  A        |     1  |       0  | colour        | blue           
  A        |     1  |       1  | price         | 1100           
  A        |     1  |       1  | token         | 1              
  A        |     1  |       1  | spc_weight    | 135*            
  A        |     1  |       1  | spc_volume    | 150*            
  A        |     1  |       1  | spc_diameter  | 12*             
  A        |     1  |       1  | colour        | blue           
  B        |     1  |       0  | price         | 800            
  B        |     1  |       0  | token         | 1              
  B        |     1  |       0  | spc_weight    | 135            
  B        |     1  |       0  | spc_volume    | 150            
  B        |     1  |       0  | spc_diameter  | 12             
  B        |     1  |       0  | colour        | red            
  B        |     2  |       0  | price         | 800            
  B        |     2  |       0  | token         | 1              
  B        |     2  |       0  | spc_weight    | 135*            
  B        |     2  |       0  | spc_volume    | 150*            
  B        |     2  |       0  | spc_diameter  | 12*             
  B        |     2  |       0  | colour        | red            
  C        |     1  |       0  | price         | 800            
  C        |     1  |       0  | token         | 2              
  C        |     1  |       0  | spc_weight    | 135            
  C        |     1  |       0  | spc_volume    | 155            
  C        |     1  |       0  | spc_diameter  | 12             
  C        |     1  |       0  | colour        | green
```

thats where I stuck right now. somehow I'm not able to write the inner join and then the update function. 
anyone some advice?

**it seems that this sql does the job:**

```
with templateCTE as ( select attribute, attributeValue
                     from product
                     where product='A'
                     and attribute like 'spc_%'
                     and model=1
                     and version=0),
productsToUpdate as ( select product, model, max (version) as version from product
                      where  attribute='token' and attributeValue='1' 
                      group by product, model ),
selectionToJoin as (select productsToUpdate.product, productsToUpdate.model,productsToUpdate.version, product.attribute, product.attributeValue from productsToUpdate
                    inner join product on productsToUpdate.product = product.product and productsToUpdate.model= product.model and productsToUpdate.version= product.version)

UPDATE P1
SET P1.[attributeValue] = P2.[attributeValue]
FROM selectionToJoin P1
JOIN templateCTE P2 ON P1.[attribute] = P2.[attribute]

COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM product
```

regards

Comment: If the user supplies a "version" as part of this template, then why are you then taking `max(version)`. Why would `product A model 1 version 1 and product B model 2 version 0` be chosen here to insert back into this table. Perhaps I just don't understand the question though. I think this would be clearer if you supplied desired results. Also you say `update function` but I feel like maybe this is an `INSERT`. Lastly, what is a `token attribute`?

Comment: Thank for your reply. each product has it's own attribute called token. the version can not be provided by the user. the version can be only provided for the template. the max version is used to find out on which products the update must me applied. insert would mean that the data entry does not exist and that would be a problem. so i guess update is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first select the source rows using a sub query then use join the product table using that resultset. Below update query will work for you -

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT [attribute], [attributeValue]
         FROM product
         WHERE [attribute] LIKE 'spc_%'
         AND [product] = 'B'
         AND [model] = 1
         AND [version] = 0)
UPDATE P1
SET P1.[attributeValue] = P2.[attributeValue]
FROM product P1
JOIN CTE P2 ON P1.[attribute] = P2.[attribute]
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c6b01/32) is the fiddle.

Comment: thanks a lot for this. i added some additional ctes to fit the condition only to update products that have the same token and are the max version.